# making my own Jquery parallax effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, parallax

I'm making a jquery parallax effect where when the user first hovers the mouse over the document, the foreground layer will move towards the mouse cursor such that the mouse cursor will be over the center of the foreground layer. Afterwards, when the user moves around the mouse cursor, the foreground layer should move the opposite direction of the mouse cursor; the  background layer will also move in the opposite direction but slower to produce the parallax effect.

The problem is that after the foreground layer moves toward the mouse cursor using the `mouseover` event and I trigger the `mousemove` event, the foreground and background layers will "jump" to another location.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jPFAq/)

Comment: Not quite sure what you're after, but I modified your fiddle to use `.animate` instead of `.css`. Now there's no jumping, but the widget feels like a butterfly fishtank of doom. http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/jPFAq/1/ You might want to put some delay in there to stop the browser from queuing up all the mouse activity. If this is what you wanted, then I'll post as an answer.

Comment: I tried that already. It's just not very responsive. I'd like to stick with the effect I have now but without the teleporting butterflies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated your example and it seems, that it works ok now (at least in Google Chrome 15 and IE9).

http://jsfiddle.net/jPFAq/10/

Basically, I have changed `mouseover` to `mouseenter` and made the coordinates calculation in `mouseenter` same as in `mousemove`.

---

**UPDATE:**
In addition I have removed the use of a variable and I'm just unsubscribing from the `mousemove` event (`jQuery.unbind`), while the `mouseenter` handler is running.

Here is the code for reference:

```
function onmousemovehandler(e){    
    mouse_dx = -(e.pageX);
    mouse_dy = -(e.pageY);
    $('#foreg').css({

        'left': mouse_dx,
        'top': mouse_dy
    });

    mouse_dx = (mouse_dx) / 2;
    mouse_dy = (mouse_dy) / 2;

    $('#backg').css({

        'left': mouse_dx,
        'top': mouse_dy

    });
};

$(document).mouseenter(function(e) {
            $(document).unbind('mousemove', onmousemovehandler);

  mouse_x = -(e.pageX);
  mouse_y = -(e.pageY);

  $('#foreg').animate({
         'left': mouse_x,
         'top': mouse_y
     }, 
     300);
  $('#backg').animate({
         'left': mouse_x/2,
         'top': mouse_y/2
     }, 
     300, 
     function() {           
         $(document).mousemove(onmousemovehandler);
        });
});
```